# What is wrong with dynamic route?

Tags: reactjs

Following this tutorial: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-pass-multiple-route-parameters-in-a-react-url-path-4b919de0abbe

I do not react dynamic parameter in component, why?

```js
// CreatePost.tsx
const CreatePost = () => {

this.props.match.params.campaignId
```

```js
// App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="createPost/:campaignId" element={<CreatePost />} />
```

got this error:

```
ERROR in src/components/CreatePost.tsx:95:21
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    93 |       rmpc = {
    94 |         md5: "9cd091c73578685c7d0740c97a935a78",
  > 95 |         campaignID: this.props.match.params.campaignId,
       |                     ^^^^
    96 |         text: postToEdit.text ?? "",
    97 |         hashtags: postToEdit.hashtags ?? "",
    98 |         link: postToEdit.link ?? "https://test",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CreatePost` component doesn't show because you've nested your dynamic route into `Layout`.

Therefore, the `Layout` component needs to be an `Outlet` so it can output (in a given layout) the routes matching your URL.

Documentation can be found [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet).

**LATER EDIT**

I see you have edited your question while I was answering your initial question.

The problem is you're accessing "this" in a functional component (see difference [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react)).

As per react-router@v6 [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) you can access the params via a hook, as follows:

```
let {campaignId} = useParams()

return (
  <div>Campaign ID: {campaignId}</div>
)
```